# How to create a multi-select listbox that allows Search in asp.net mvc jQuery

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Can someone please provide me information about how to create a multi-select listbox/dropdown that supports search of it's items?

I'm using ASP.Net MVC 3, JQuery for this project. Please note that I'm very new to ASP.NET MVC. Detailed information is much appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've achieved this using the Chosen JQuery plugin - http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/

Comment: Please could u provide code samples. I am having issues with it being that it does not work and I am using ASP.NET MVC 4. Thanks in advance